# .Net Assembly missing on MATLAB

Tags: .net, matlab, dll

I am using Matlab 2018b having Matlab Compiler Tool.
But while using Library compiler, there is no option of `.Net` Assembly, my need is to convert `.m` file to `.dll` which is to be used in visual studio.

[image: .Net Assembly missing]

Comment: That sounds like a good question for the Matlab support

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Someone else cross-posted this in MATLAB Answers and [Nikilesh Chilkuru](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/13045811-nikilesh-chilkuru) answered - [he said](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/440385-net-assembly-missing):

> With MATLAB Compiler, you can compile a MATLAB script to an executable and to an Excel Add-in. However to compile a MATLAB script to a .Net Assembly, you need to have [MATLAB Compiler SDK](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-compiler-sdk.html) installed. MATLAB Compiler SDK extends the functionality of [MATLAB Compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler.html) to let you build C/C++ shared libraries, .NET assemblies, Java classes, and Python packages from MATLAB programs.